# Why are my media files not working in production

Tags: django, apache, media

For server I am using Linode, as DataBase MySql, and apache2. The static files working perfectly, but images(media files) does not display :(. Already tried to restart server and change the urls.py file!

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

project configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/artashes/multi/static
        <Directory /home/artashes/multi/static>
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/artashes/multi/media
        <Directory /home/artashes/multi/static>
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/artashes/multi/multisad>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/artashes/multi/multisad/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/artashes/multi python-home=/home/artashes/multi/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app


</VirtualHost>
```

White a comment if you need more details! I will edit this question )

Comment: When you upload an image via a View, do you see that file in the `/home/artashes/multi/media`?

Comment: Storing **shared** files in **private** home directory of a specific user is not a good idea.

Comment: @schillingt no its not added